# JAR execution different from eclipse execution

Tags: java, jar, position, execution

I have an issue with my jar execution. I have a java code that finds positions of elements in a txt file. When I execute it on eclipse, it works perfectly.

However when I execute the jar file from that code, the returned positions are not the same.

For example: in eclipse I have [45,64] and the jar gives me [48,67].

What could be the origin of this problem?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the text file?  Can you also show us the Java code which is opening, reading, and evaluating the text file?